# Slim Docker Image contains git repository

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, docker

I have a requirements.txt file which contains the following package:

```
git+https://username:password@gitlab.mycompany.com/mypackage.git@master#egg=mypackage
```

I am able to build my docker image using a basic dockerfile.
However, I'm trying to use a more complex docker file to get my docker image to be as slim as possible:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine as base
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

FROM base AS dependencies
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN apk add --no-cache make automake gcc g++ git  && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM base
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY --from=dependencies /root/.cache /root/.cache
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && rm -rf /root/.cache
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python main.py
```

The problem is that during the last phase of the build I get error which 'git' cannot be found, i.e The build tries to pull 'mypackage' instead of taking it from the "dependencies" part. Any idea how to fix this?

The error:

```
 Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'git': 'git' while executing command git clone -q     Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `git` in your last (3rd) image, because you only have `git` in `dependencies`, while the last one derives from `base`, which is pure alpine python.

So when you try to `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && rm -rf /root/.cache`, you fail on requirement with `git` protocol.

If you need your final image to be slim, there are few options how to fix it:

- use `venv` (Python's virtual environment); create it on 2nd step and `COPY` to last one. Then there no need to install requirements.
- download reqs from repository to local disk on 2nd step, then `COPY` them to 3rd step and install (may need `gcc` on 3rd step, but not `git`)

Comment: **venv** is what I was looking for! I Used this great blog post to implement :
[python-docker-multi-stage-builds](https://www.lutro.me/posts/python-docker-multi-stage-builds). 
My Docker image reduced to 240MB including pandas and numpy, not sure if it's possible to make it more slim.